# Using Glossary in Latexian (editor)

Tags: glossaries, mac

I am using [Latexian](http://tacosw.com/latexian/) for OS X. But I can't get the Glossary working.
I followed the steps on http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary, but I don't see a Glossary.

Can someone help me?